# Does convergence of $\Gamma(x)$ imply convergence of $\Gamma(z)$? Is it generalisable?

Tags: complex-analysis, gamma-function, absolute-convergence

If we have the gamma function in integral form $\Gamma(x)=\int_\limits0^\infty e^{-t}t^{x-1}dt$ and have proven that it converges for real $x>0$ (to a point), can we then immediately conclude that $\Gamma(z)$ converges to a point if Re($z$)$>0$?

I'm asking this because we note that $t^{z-1}$ is complex and thus can be written in polar form $re^{i\varphi}$. The distance between the origin and $t^{z-1}$ is equal to $r>0$. We can now easily associate *this* distance with the distance between $x=r$ and the origin. We already know that $\Gamma(x)$ converges, thus $\Gamma(z)$ must converge to a given distance from the origin. **However**, we have completely ignored the angle $\varphi$. Do we know that the angle converges? If so, how?

If $\Gamma(z)$ converges, can we somehow generalise the idea?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by $\int_a^b$. Is this a path integral from $a$ to $b$? Can it be any path? Why do you think that $\int_a^b |f(z)|\text{d}z$ is positive? What do you mean by "$|a| = \infty$"

Comment: I have completely changed my question to 1) make it more accurate and 2) more understable. I hope everything is clear and correctly worded now.

Comment: For $x =\Re(z)$ and $0 < a < b < \infty$ then $\int_a^b e^{-t} t^{x-1}dt=\int_a^b |e^{-t} t^{z-1}|dt$ so $\Gamma(z,a,b)=\int_a^b e^{-t} t^{z-1}dt$ converges. Since $e^{-u} u^{z-1}$ is analytic for $\Re(u) > 0$ it implies that $\Gamma(z,a,b)=\oint_a^b e^{-t} t^{z-1}dt$ for any finite length path $a\to b$. Letting $b \to +\infty$ you have a result for $\Gamma(z) = \lim_{b \to +\infty} \Gamma(z,1/b,b)$.

Comment: Now a stronger result is that $\Gamma(z) = \lim_{\Re(b) \to +\infty} \Gamma(z,0,b)$ (for example $\Gamma(z) = \lim_{c \to +\infty} \Gamma(z,0,c(1+i))$) and this is because $e^{-u}u^{z-1}$ decreases very fast as $\Re(u) \to +\infty$ so that for any $\Re(s) > 0$ then $\lim_{c \to +\infty} \oint_c^{cs} e^{-u} u^{z-1}du= 0$. The limiting case $s =\pm i$ is interesting too.

Comment: @reuns Okay, so $x=$Re$(z)$ follows from $|e^{-t}t^{z-1}|=e^{-t}\sqrt{t^{x+iy-1}\cdot t^{x-iy-1}}$, then the equality between the integrals follows indeed, but why then "so $\Gamma(z,a,b)=\int\limits_a^b e^{-t}t^{z-1}dt$ converges"?

Comment: When you say that the function --let's call it $f(z,t)$-- is analytic, do you mean that that implies that we can take any path from a to b in our domain? I assume so, but then I'm not sure what to make of $\oint_a^b$.

Sorry for responding this late